# chat bot , node js , access json data

Tags: node.js, bots

i am creating a chatbot using node js and ms bot framework , i wanted to access the data from data.js but i am getting undefine result i cant access the date of the example "west" , any problem with the code?
[image: chabot result screenshot]
data.js

```
let salesData  = {
  west: [
    { units: "200", total: "100 pesos" },
   { title: "In The End", artist: "Linkin Park" }

  ],
  func: function() {

  }
};

module.exports = salesData ;
```

app.js

```
let salesData  = require('./Dialogs/data.js');
salesData .func();
bot.dialog('getSalesData', [
    function (session) {
        builder.Prompts.choice(session, "Which region would you like sales for?", salesData); 
    },
    function (session, results) {
        if (results.response) {
            var region = salesData[results.response.entity];
            session.send(`We sold ${region.units} units for a total of ${region.total}.`); 
        } else {
            session.send("OK");
        }
    }
]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `salesData.west` is an array.

When getting the units, you need to do `region[0].units`.

However, being index bound is not a good idea, so you might want to restructure your `salesData.west` if possible.

Going by your current `app.js` structure, this should be your **data.js**

```
let salesData = {
    west: {
        units: "200",
        total: "100 pesos",
        title: "In The End",
        artist: "Linkin Park"
    },
    func: function() {

    }
};
```

Comment: can you provide me the structure?

Comment: the structure will depend on your requirements and use cases, it differs on what you need

Comment: how about based on the code i have show above Sir>? this format i wanted to access var salesData = {
    "west": {
        units: 200,
        total: "$6,000"
    },
    "central": {
        units: 100,
        total: "$3,000"
    },
    "east": {
        units: 300,
        total: "$9,000"
    }
};

Comment: why don't you use this one then? why have you made `west` an array?

Comment: i dont know how to access it from seperate file , can you tell me how? is this correct (let salesData  = require('./Dialogs/data.js'); ?

Comment: but is still show an undefine result and errors, can you provide the whole structure of code? in my data.js using var salesData = { "west": { units: 200, total: "$6,000" }, "central": { units: 100, total: "$3,000" }, "east": { units: 300, total: "$9,000" } }; .

Comment: can you fix my data.js Sir ? can you provide it for me?

Comment: i will try it sir

Comment: your `salesData .func();` has a ` `(space) between them , try removing it

Comment: module.exports = salesData; this is the one i forgot i have fixed it thank you